# Outline won't go in btn-group buttons of Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm got it working for a single button to remove the outline but I can't seem to get it off for a `btn-group` class.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fdbzkc7x/)**

Here's my HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button without outline</button>
<hr />
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Button with outline
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Button with outline
              </label>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}
[class*="btn-"]:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.focus` instaed `:focus` beacuse bootstrap add `focus` class `onfocus` what apply `box-shadow` style

```
[class*="btn-"] .focus {
     box-shadow: none
}
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdbzkc7x/5/)

Comment: Oh so simple. Thank You so much. Will accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: happy to help :)